# Custom permissions in Django REST API don't raise any error even when print() function returns False in the terminal

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I wrote a permission:

```
class IsParticipant(permissions.BasePermission):
  def has_permission(self, request, view):
     return True

  def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

    if isinstance(obj, Message):
        return request.user in obj.chat.chat_participants.all()
    elif ....


    return False
```

I checked, conditions work correctly (now I need just the first if condition), the program enters the if condition, and returns False or True (I've written print() function, so it showed in terminal that program returns False of True depending on values). But it doesn't change anything, even if returns False, it doesn't forbid anything for user. It even doesn't raise any default error.
Here is the view class (although I don't think it is necessary here):

```
class WriteMessageCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsParticipant]
serializer_class = WriteMessageSerializer #the model is named as 'Message'

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.validated_data['author'] = self.request.user
    serializer.validated_data['chat_id'] = self.kwargs['pk']
    return super(WriteMessageCreateAPIView, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

So the questions are: Why the permission class doesn't do anything? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try by doing
`permission_classes = [IsParticipant]`

It will work I think, I had the same issue few days ago and I found out that the
`permission_classes = [ ]` is giving the 'or' of the classes and not the 'and', I mean if either of the permission class  is true, then it is returning true. (or permitting the user)

You may directly add what you wanna do in views.py by overriding the post function. (or whichever is needed)

Comment: Worked for me. Well that's all I knew about it.

Answer (score 0):

if you use many permissions need to indicate how they relate to each other

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/#composable-permission-classes

for example:

```
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated | IsParticipant)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding

```
obj = get_object_or_404(Chat, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
```

to my perform_create function in WriteMessageCreateAPIView class.
Now it works: checks if the user is a participant of the chat group or not. If not, denies permission related with that chat group for the user.